# Chances of Sql injection if i remove all the special characters?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

if i remove all the special characters from a string than is there any chance of sql injection??(i don't need any special characters in my input)

i am using following code to remove all special characters

```
    $unsafe = $_GET["tag"];
$safe = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/s', '', $unsafe);
$safe = mysql_real_escape_string($safe);
```

is there still any chances of having sql injection??

Comment: even with the special characters, just running it through `mysql_real_escape_string` should be enough. However, why even take the chance of sql injection? Just use pdo/mysqli and bind the parameters. It is simple.

Comment: At some point, you *will* need the unsafe characters. Just do it properly to start with. You'll save yourself many many headaches.

Comment: thanks but i have a ready application with mysql so converting it to PDO will be a big headache thats why using this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `mysql_real_escape_string`, then there's no reason to remove "unsafe characters", since it will make them all safe.

However, the `mysql_*` functions are not recommended, since they're hard to use correctly. The PHP developers now recommend using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or the [`mysqli_*` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/212555) for how to use parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: The mysql_real_escape_string function is not a catch-all. It only escapes special characters, so SELECT * FROM users WHERE score = $var is still vulnerable to $var = "1 OR 1 = 1"

Comment: @BadalSurana So always quote your variables (`SELECT * FROM users WHERE score = '$var'`), or even better -- **use parametrized queries with PDO or mysqli** (I just added a link to an answer showing some examples).

Comment: thank you but i have a ready application with mysql so converting it to PDO will be a big headache thats why using this.

Comment: @BadalSurana Then I already answered your question -- removing unsafe characters won't do you any good if you're already using `mysql_real_escape_string`. `mysql_real_escape_string` can only help you if your input is being treated as strings (hence the name). If you're passing in variables unquoted then you have a much bigger security problem (since all input is being treated as raw SQL).

Comment: okay so quoting variables and using `mysql_real_escape_string` will make it sql injection free??

Comment: @BadalSurana As long as you do it *every single time*. I highly recommend learning to use PDO or mysqli as soon as you have time though, since parametrized queries are much easier to do correctly.

Comment: I converted from mysql_ to PDO on a very large application a couple of years back and it only took an afternoon.  What made it a bit easier was that I had an abstraction layer already, and I kept all my database access in my "model" (kept my database access code separate to my logic or view code).  I even parameterised all my queries.  I had probably 100-200 queries that I did this for.

Unfortunately if you are maintaining someone else's app and it's terribly written (random direct calls to mysql_query() all over the place) then it's going to be more difficult...